# could not resolve type R.anim

Tags: android

I have  three projets involved on this issue
First project API (Contains the interface)
Second project draw my menu and calls the interface method

```
mItemClick.expandViewPageAdapter((BaseActivity)getActivity());
```

And the third project implements the interface

```
public class FragmentFullMenuSmartphone extends Fragment implements PerformActionController {

@Override
public void expandViewPageAdapter(BaseActivity activity) {
  activity
            .getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.translate_left_full_from_end,
                    R.anim.translate_left_full_from_start,
                    R.anim.translate_right_full_to_start, 
                    R.anim.translate_right_full_to_end)
            .replace(R.id.transactional_content_smartphone, new FragmentViewPager(),FragmentViewPager.TAG).addToBackStack(BACKSTACK_FULL_MENU).commit();

}
```

The problem is: I can´t find the mynamespace.R class if I call android.R it´s ok.

adding more info:

My interface is in project 1 (API)

```
import br.com.bb.android.BaseActivity;

public interface PerformActionController {

    void expandViewPageAdapter(BaseActivity activity);

}
```

My class that calls the interface method

```
public class MenuContentFragment extends FacebankTabFragment implements OnFinishLoadFaceBankService {

private static PerformActionController mItemClick;

public static MenuContentFragment newInstance(PerformActionController itemClick) {
    mItemClick = itemClick;
    MenuContentFragment mcf = new MenuContentFragment();

    return mcf;
}

 protected void buildMenuItem(ItemDeMenuTransacional item, boolean isSubmenu) {
    containerItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ItemDeMenuTransacional selectedItem = (ItemDeMenuTransacional)v.getTag();

            if (selectedItem.isLeaf()) {
                mItemClick.expandViewPageAdapter((BaseActivity)getActivity());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code that you have added, doesn't reference to R.anim, can you please update the code in the question to include it.

Comment: I figured out that it can´t find the R.id too :/

Comment: What is the name of your package? Is R.string working for you?

Comment: R.string is not working. The name of the package is irrelevant.

Comment: Did you check your build/generated/source/r/debug/your.package.name/ folder is there any R class?

Comment: Robin asked me the same questions. and I answer it in another comment. The file is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on! I was compiling it in a Nexus 5 phone with android L. And this version is still full of bugs. I tested in another phones and everything is ok now.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

`android.R` is for system resources (stock icons, etc.). Your `R` class is for your own assets. If `R` cannot be resolved, it usually means there's an error in one of your resource files, preventing the `R` class from being generated.

Comment: I´m using this same resource in other class. Seems that compiler can´t find my mynamespace.R class at all, I can´t find id or anim or attr nothing :(

Comment: Are you using different packages? If you're not using the package that you specified in the manifest, you have to include `R` manually.

Comment: Do you mean Projects or packages? The anim files is in the third project, same project I´m implementing the interface method.

Comment: My activity and my fragment are in the same package on the third project, and I´m importing the R class import mynamespace.R.

Comment: Can you verify that the `R` class actually exists in the `gen` directory, and that it has the `anim` field?

Comment: It´s there, I tried here to call secondprojectnamespace.R and firstprojectnamespace.R and it´s not able to find as well. Its happening in this method specifically I can access in others methods like onCreateView I can inflate my layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio? I've found that AS sometimes decides to forget where your R file is. Restarting Android Studio works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround for this issue.
I declare the resource as a instance variable
like:

```
private final int resource = <mynamespace>.R.anim.<animname>
```

and I use this latter. I didn´t understand why this specifically method can´t find my resource file. Well I will keep looking.

If anyone figure it out please let me know.

Thank you guys.